# class diagram mvc javascript&C#

Tags: model-view-controller, uml, class-diagram

I roughly know how to make a mvc uml class diagram en can find enough info/ examples on the internet. The only thing i cant find info about is if it makes a difference when you have a jacascript controller/model and a c# controller/model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: no.
UML is technology independent. Most models don't assume the technology. MVC can also be applied to different programming languages.

You only need to be aware that there are some concepts that are not handled by particular languages. The only thing that comes to my mind here is multiinheritance. Just use interfaces instead of (eventual) multiinheritance and there'll be no problem.

I can also imagine that some details can be designed in different ways to achieve better performance, but you'd need to know both languages perfectly to be able to make such decisions.

So don't bother about specific language and your diagram will be fine.

Comment: What about a multilanguage class diagram. So a project that uses both c# and javascript( javascript for the front end- c# backend). i know its bit late to ask further, but just needed to know

Comment: I would say it's a good point to make a separate question. But anyway - as I was mentioning on some level you ignore technology completely. Only when you're designing your code you start taking technology into consideration. Now in such case your c# and javascript parts would be somewhat separated so you should set them in separate packages and create separate diagrams for them. What is more important to depict (in my opinion) is the interaction between those packages, but that's what you present on behavioural diagrams, and the static relationship on components diagram.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, i think i know what to do now. still gonna make a separate question, maybe somebody else has a some more info about this.